# Is it better to increase Dex or Con to increase a squishy hard-caster's overall longevity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, ability-scores

Would pumping one stat over the other increase the overall longevity as it pertains to a squishy hard-caster? (Wizard/Druid/Sorcerer/Witch types). I am not talking about about any skills or class features but more of the following:

Higher AC vs. more HP
Reflex saves vs. Fortitude saves

Pretty much which core stat gives the best chance of long-term survival.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like many things in 3.5, this is a relationship that flips as you advance in levels. If you start past the very early levels, Dexterity quickly stops being key to survival.

## Early levels: DEX keeps you alive

When you're in the 1-5 level range, you have only a few hit dice, and bonuses are scarce. Having 1-5 extra HP is not meaningful; it is smaller than most damage dice. There are very few cool Fortitude effects flying around. Your fighter buddy isn't that far ahead in HP yet, either, but he does have really good AC thanks to his cheap armours, and you can't afford your thistledown githcraft whatevers just yet.

## Late levels: DEX does nothing to keep you safe

Once you can afford the cool gear and magic doodads, the role of Dexterity as a fraction of your AC greatly diminishes. All the high-level Reflex saves are just against damage dice, and anyone who wants attacks that ignore AC entirely has had them for ages now. In the meantime, Fortitude saves prevent you from being turned into a frog. Every point of CON bonus counts for 10-20 hit points, which is quite a lot compared to the HP you get from rolling hit dice.

Comment: Even though I said it wasn't in this iteration of the question, Dex affects many more skills and the ranged attack bonus of many spells. But generally I agree with your analysis

Comment: The one important thing DEX will keep doing for you is faster initiative, and those that can go first and react (or escape) can survive longer.

Comment: @Rob: Dex will continue boosting everything it contributes to, only the *fraction* contributed by Dex diminishes. This is true for Initiative too: the *Warning* weapon enchantment is a +5 bonus, the *Nerveskitter* spell is another +5 bonus, the *Improved Initiative* feat is a +4 bonus. At 1st level your Dex contributes 100% of your Initiative; at 10th level it is probably down to 50%, depending on whether you have a high Dex or not.

Comment: @MatthieuM. : Each bonus point for initiative is important, as that is the difference with you opponent that matters and in normal games you will never reach the point where you have so much more than them that more points don't give you significatively more chance to play before them. +2 to init is +2 to init, whatever it is 100% or 20% of your whole bonus.

Comment: @AnneAunyme: There is a balance though; if you use everything to pump initiative, but cannot kill/immobilize the foes in your first round, you must then endure their retaliation. If you boost Dex, it is at the detriment of something else...

Comment: with [the right feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/slashing-grace-combat) or [the right class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/unchained-classes/rogue-unchained), DEX is by far better than CON to make you able to kill your opponent quickly.

Comment: @AnneAunyme The questions specifically excludes class features, and talks about spellcasters.

Comment: Rays are ranged attacks, so Dex does apply to damage output a bit sans any feat. Weapon Finesse and weapon specialization: Ray or touch are legitimate choices by the RAW, as well, and a wizard could benefit from them.

Answer (score 1):

I speak from a Pathfinder point of view. It may be true on DD3.5 too.

Let's see what DEX and CON are good for:

DEX: initiative, AC, reflex saves, skills, hit with ranged weapons

CON: HP, vigor saves

Now, let's examine these features:

- **AC** is very powerful in early levels, as even the strong opponents have a good chance to miss you if you try to have a decent AC. If you play a druid dwarf with a stone plate, please, get that +1. At higher levels however it becomes less powerful as many monsters will just have either a too high bonus to be able to miss you, or offensive capacities that ignore AC. At best it will make the last attacks of the full round miss, which is useless if you are already dead with the first ones.
- **HP** is useful whatever the level. That's what keeps you alive ! As an example at lvl 1 if you go from 10 to 12 in CON you earn only 1 HP but you gain also 2 more negative HP that do not kill you. Virtually it is like passing from 6(+10) to 7(+12).
- **saves** are important, but reflex is in general the less important of all. Most of the time it will just let you avoid half the damage, whereas a successful vigor save let you avoid very nasty effects. However some GM are very creative at finding use to reflex save, so it could be more useful at your table.
- **initiative** is important. If you play before your opponent you can neutralize him before he neutralize you, or at least avoid being neutralized before being able to act. Vs packed small foes you can cast *fireball* before they split up, vs big bosses you can cast *haste* so your teammates can do wonders, or a debuff that will be active when he will play.
- **bonus to hit** with ranged weapon applies to ray attacks, like *enervation* or *scorching ray*. As you only have to hit contact AC, you won't have any problem to hit big monsters, but at early levels, where the monsters are not that big, contact AC can be difficult to hit with your 1/2 BAB.
- **skills** are a bonus. Some of them like *escape artist* or *acrobatics* may directly be linked to your survival.

As a conclusion: HP > AC, vigor > reflex, but DEX have other features that are far from being useless, especially at early levels.

Comment: What is "CA"?  I'm not familiar with that term.

Comment: It's "AC" in French, I corrected it.